# SAML enabled system Content Porter not working

Tags: sites-9

Just sharing this knowledge/error messages for community users.

After moving to SAML setup, not able to use Content Porter anymore: can not connect to core services API.

```
Access is denied for the user .

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport
Errorcode: 770
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable1 claims)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(IEnumerable`1 claims)
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.SessionHelper.GetCurrentSession()
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Service.ImportExportServiceBase.TestConnection()
at SyncInvokeTestConnection(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Also configured ImportExport service web.config to use LDAP module and updated the endpoint to use LDAP or SAML recommented configs. Tested the content Porter LDAP users still not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SAML implementation limitations](https://docs.sdl.com/792149/749306/sdl-tridion-sites-9/saml-implementation-limitations)

SAML 2.0 only works with the browser-based clients, Content Manager Explorer and Experience Manager.

It **does not work** with the desktop clients, Template Builder and **Content Porter**, nor with APIs. Such clients require another way of authentication (LDAP).

It's mandatory to [Configure Directory Service](https://docs.sdl.com/792149/677735/sdl-tridion-sites-9/configuring-directory-services) for search and add users and Content Porter and Template Builder functionalites to work.

**Note:**
It also same case for sites 9.5 with access management

I hope it helps.